# Create document Failed in MongoDB mLab UI

Tags: mongodb, mlab

{
    "denomination" : "10c",
    "quantity" : 20,
    "total" : 2.00,
    "inStockStatus" : "Y",
    "code" = "0.1",
    "updatedBy" = "system",
    "updatedDate" = new Date()
 }

Failed to create new document!

> We encountered an error while parsing your JSON. Please check your syntax (e.g. ensure you are using double quotes around both your field names and values) and try again.

I can do one by one but I'm not familiar with mongoDB, I want to insert exactly one row at a time just like other DB (i.e mySQL, Oracle..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Date()` is JavaScript code and not strict JSON. If you need insert documents that contain dynamically generated values via JavaScript code, you'll need to use a client like the `mongo` shell (which is a JavaScript interpreter).

Alternatively, here is more details on how to represent a date value as JSON: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#date

Edit: Already mentioned in another answer - swap any '=' with ':' as well.

Answer (score 0):

For some of your fields you have an '=' where you need a ':'.  This document should work:

```
{ "denomination" : "10c", "quantity" : 20, "total" : 2.00, "inStockStatus" : "Y", "code" : "0.1", "updatedBy" : "system", "updatedDate" : new Date() }
```